# How to get client's identity in an app running in VPC accessed via AWS's Client VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, saml, vpn, identity

For internal tools, I'm running a web app inside of a VPC, and connecting to it via AWS's Client VPN. I set up Google as my SAML identity provider to be able to do SSO for accessing the VPN, which works fine. However, I can't find a way to get the client's identity inside of my web app to be able to have fine-grained access control and logging. Is this even possible? Or do I have to make the user sign in again once they're on VPN?

Answer (score 0):

you can implement Google SSO for your apps as well so that the client will not need to sign on again once he/she signed on VPN.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).